# what are the most interesting long standing problems in low-dimensional topology?

Tags: low-dimensional-topology

What are the problem most interesting problems that people who do research in low dimensional topology have been working on in the past decade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a small list see [here](https://ldtopology.wordpress.com/open-problems/). For example,  "The smooth 4-dimensional Poincare conjecture", or "Garoufalidis’s slope conjecture". For a nice survey on problems on low-dimensional topology, see [here](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~ildt/prob15.pdf), from $2015$ in Kyoto. There is also a related [MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32292/what-are-some-of-the-big-open-problems-in-3-manifold-theory).